# Problem with links & base page

Tags: links, base-page

I have Civicrm 4.7.20 installed on Wordpress 4.8.

When I create a new event or contribution the link that Civicrm creates does not work.
What Civicrm creates as a link:
http://[mysite]/?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm/event/register&reset=1&id=7
This link loads my Civicrm base page, in this case my home page.  If I change the base page to a different page then that page is loaded.

This link works:
http://[mysite]/?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm/event/info1&reset=1&id=7&page_id=1811

Note the &page_id=1811 parameter

As long as I specify the parameter &page_id=[any valid page] the link works, if I don't specify then the link loads the base page.

I tried disabling all other plugins and nothing changed so I think it has to be a Wordpress or Civicrm setting problem.

Comment: Is WordPress installed in a sub-directory or the root directory of the site?

Comment: WordPress is installed on the root directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do you have Permalinks 'plain' enabled (in WP Dashboard/Settings)? Or do you have custom? I don't know if that makes a difference but it relates to how URLs are constructed. I switched between plain and custom Permalinks. And in civicrm Wordpress Integration how did you configure your 'base' page?  I used the postname of my WP base page (ie, just 'civicrm') and it seems to work, civicrm event pages show.
Does your .htaccess file have URL rewriting enabled (begins like "# BEGIN WordPress

RewriteEngine On.."
In the URL for, say, an event I get "page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm%2Fevent%2Finfo&id=1870&reset=1" where &id=1870 is the registration form for an event I created.
 I am using 4.7.20 and WP 4.8 also

Comment: And check what is the permalink for your civicrm base page (edit the page in WP)

Comment: Adding "RewriteEngine On" block from https://codex.wordpress.org/htaccess to .htaccess fixed the problem, now the civicrm generated link works.  http://<mysite>/civicrm/?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm/event/info&reset=1&id=7